# Is there some escaped_list_separator reverse function?

Tags: c++

I am aware one can use boost escaped_list_separator to split a string and remove the escaping at the same time.

Is there a similar (elegant) way to achieve the reverse result? Like joining multiple strings into one while adding escapings?

Comment: Not a C++ developer, so I can't speak to whether it will meet your needs, but http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/string_algo/reference.html#header.boost.algorithm.string.join_hpp appears appropriate?

Comment: @SeanBright, the predicate just tests the input, while in process of using `join`, I need to change the input, by escaping specific characters.

Comment: Can you just run a function `escape()` on each item before you `join` them all?

Comment: @Keeler, definitely that is a possibility, I was looking for some sort of one liners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you want a one-liner, but can't find anything that meets your needs.

With a `string escape(const string &s)` function, you could write your own one-liner:

```
#include <algorithm>

string escape(const string &s)
{
    // Do your thing.
    return result;
}

string joinEscaped(const vector<string> &v, const string &delimiter)
{
    std::vector<string> temp(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), temp.begin(), escape);

    return boost::algorithm::join(temp, delimiter);
}
```